# Function pointer to different functions with different arguments in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have two functions with variable number and types of arguments

```
double my_func_one(double x, double a, double b, double c) { return x + a + b + c }
double my_func_two(double x, double p[], double c) { return x + p[0] + p[1] + c }
```

I want to use a pointer to a function to the functions I defined above based on a some condition getting true e.g.

```
if (condition_1)
   pfunc = my_func_one;
else if (condition_2)
   pfunc = my_func_two;

 // The function that will use the function I passed to it
 swap_function(a, b, pfunc);
```

My question is, for this scenario, Can I at all define a function pointer? If yes, how?
My understanding is that the prototype of function pointer should be the same for all those functions it CAN be pointed to.

```
typedef double (*pfunction)(int, int);
```

In my case they are not the same. Is there any other way to do this?

## Language

I am developing in C and I am using gcc 4.4.3 compiler/linker

Comment: Make the function pointer a `void *`, and then do proper typecasting when being called? You loose all manner of type-safety though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My question is, for this scenario, Can I at all define a function pointer?

No.  (Other than by dirty typecasting.)

> Is there any other way to do this?

Your best bet is to create a wrapper function for one of your existing functions.  For example:

```
double my_func_one_wrapper(double x, double p[], double c) {
    return my_func_one(x, p[0], p[1], c);
}
```

That way, you have two functions with the same signature, and therefore the same function-pointer type.

Answer (score 35):

The cleanest way to do it is to use a union:

```
typedef union {
  double (*func_one)(double x, double a, double b, double c);
  double (*func_two)(double x, double p[], double c);
} func_one_two;
```

Then you can initialize an instance of the union, and include information to the `swap_function` function to say which field is valid:

```
func_one_two func;

if (condition_1)
   func.func_one = my_func_one;
else if (condition_2)
   func.func_two = my_func_two;

 // The function that will use the function I passed to it
 swap_function(a, b, func, condition_1);
```

This assumes that `swap_function` can know based on `condition_1` being `false` that it should assume `condition_2`. Note that the union is passed by value; it's only a function pointer in size after all so that's not more expensive than passing a pointer to it.

Answer (score 3):

An old topic but I am facing same issue and finally came with this idea.

If you want the same prototype for each functions you can wrap the parameters in structure like this :

```
 typedef struct {
     double a,
            b,
            c; 
 }chunk1_t;

  typedef struct {
     double p[];
     double c; 
 }chunk2_t;
```

Then your function pointer becomes:

```
 double (*pfunc) (double x, void *args);
```

which leads to something like this :

```
 pfunc cb;

 double swap_function(double x, pfunc cb, void *args);

 double my_func_one(double x, void *args) { 
   chunk1_t *chunk = (chunk1_t*) args;
   return x + chunk->a + chunk->b + chunk->c; 
 }

 double my_func_two(double x, void *args) {
   chunk2_t *chunk = (chunk2_t*) args;
   return x + chunk->p[0] + chunk->p[1] + chunk->c ;
 }

 int main(){
   // declare a, b,...
   double a = 1.0f;
   //...
   // cast for safety
   chunk1_t myChunk1 = {(double)a, (double)b, (double)c};
   // don't if you like risk
   chunk2_t myChunk2 = {p, c};

   swap_function(x, cb, &myChunk1); 
   swap_function(x, cb, &myChunk2);
 }
```

**Using function pointer stored in structure:**

```
 #define FUNC_ONE_METHOD 1
 #define FUNC_TWO_METHOD 2

 typedef struct chunk{
     double a, b, c;
     double p[];
     int method;
     double (*pfunc) (double x, struct chunk *self);
 }chunk_t;

 double swap_function(double x, chunk_t *ch){
    switch (ch->method)
    {
        case FUNC_TWO_METHOD:
            ch->pfunc = my_func_two;
            break;
        case FUNC_ONE_METHOD:
            ch->pfunc = my_func_one;
            break;
        default:
            return -1; // or throw error
    return ch->pfunc(x, ch);
 }


 chunk c = {.a= 1, .b=3, .c=1, .method=1};
 swap_function(x, &c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is true.
The signature of your function-pointer must match the corresponding function(s).

Consider [learncpp.com](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/):

> Just like it is possible to declare a non-constant pointer to a variable, it’s also possible to >declare a non-constant pointer to a function. The syntax for doing so is one of the ugliest things >you will ever see:

```
// pFoo is a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns an integer 
int (*pFoo) ();
```

> The parenthesis around *pFoo are necessary for precedence reasons, as int `*pFoo()` would be interpreted as a function named `pFoo` that takes no parameters and returns a pointer to an integer.
>
> In the above snippet, `pFoo` is a pointer to a function that has no parameters and returns an integer. `pFoo` can “point” to any function that matches this signature.
>
> ...
>
> Note that the signature (parameters and return value) of the function pointer must match the signature of the function.

Comment: well, actually `pFoo` is a pointer to a function that can take an arbitrary amount of parameters of any type. see https://godbolt.org/z/Y8M3jP

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible, but a bit dirty. Function pointers can be cast to one another without losing information. The important thing is that you'd always have to **call** a function through such a pointer only with a signature that corresponds to its definition. So *if* you cast back before calling the function(s) and call with the correct arguments, all should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

A sample of Typecasting approach for using a same function pointer for different functions of different prototypes.
<>

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void (*myFuncPtrType) (void);

typedef int (*myFunc2PtrType)(int, int);

typedef int * (*myFunc3PtrType)(int *);

static void myFunc_1 (void);
static int myFunc_2 (int, int);
static int* myFunc_3 (int *);

const myFuncPtrType myFuncPtrA[] = {
                                    (myFuncPtrType)myFunc_1,
                                    (myFuncPtrType)myFunc_2,
                                    (myFuncPtrType)myFunc_3
};

static void myFunc_1 (void)
{
    printf("I am in myFunc_1 \n");
}

static int myFunc_2 (int a, int b)
{
    printf("I am in myFunc_2\n");
    return (a+b);
}

static int* myFunc_3 (int *ptr)
{
    printf("I am in myFunc_3\n");
    *ptr = ((*ptr) * 2);
    return (ptr+1);
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int A[2],C;

    int* PTR = A;

    (*(myFuncPtrA[0]))();

    A[0]=5;
    A[1]=6;

    C = ((myFunc2PtrType)(*(myFuncPtrA[1])))(A[0],A[1]);

    printf("Value of C: %d \n", C);

    printf("Value of PTR before myFunc_3: %p \n", PTR);
    printf("Value of *PTR before myFunc_3: %d \n", *PTR);

    PTR = ((myFunc3PtrType)(*(myFuncPtrA[2])))(&A);

    //Lets look how PTR has changed after the myFunc_3 call

    printf("Value of PTR after myFunc_3: %p \n", PTR);
    printf("Value of *PTR after myFunc_3: %d \n", *PTR);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a description of what you have done ? Instead of just pasting the code.